# undefined method OOP and PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am getting error. Can you look at it? I am sitting on it and cant figure it. ExtendedEmailer is second sub class. Edit when I change change call It works..I can echo sender...but now gettin gFatal error: Call to undefined method Extendedemailer::sendHTMLEmail()

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method HtmlEmailer::setSender()

```
 $a = new HtmlEmailer("asdada");
 $a->setSender("asdad");
 $a->addRecipients("asdad");
 $a->setSubject("asdaasdadd");
 $a->setBody("qweqwe");
 $a->sendHTMLEmail();
```

and this is where I set sender

```
class.extendedemailer.php
        class Extendedemailer extends emailer
        {
        function __construct(){}
           public function setSender($sender)
           {
           echo $sender;
           $this->sender = $sender;
           }
        }

class.htmlemailer.php
    class HtmlEmailer extends emailer
    {
     public function sendHTMLEmail()
     {
      foreach ($this->recipients as $recipient)
      {
      ......          
      if($result) echo "HTML successfully sent to {$recipient}<br/>";
      }
     }

    }
index.php
class emailer   
{
 protected $sender;           
 protected $recipients;
 private $subject;
 private $body;
 function __construct($sender)
 {
 $this->sender = $sender;  
 }
```

Comment: You did not define a class called `HtmlEmailer`. It is called `Extendedemailer `.

Comment: `$a = new HtmlEmailer("asdada");` , but you described `setSender` in  `Extendedemailer`, not `HtmlEmailer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setSender() is implemented in the Extendedemailer class, not in HtmlEmailer.
Also - in php7/phpng calling a non-static method as a static method is deprecated and you should stop using it.